# Ionic error during build (Debug failure)

Tags: angular, debugging, ionic-framework

When I try to build my project with either `ionic cordova run android` or `ionic serve -c`, I run into this error, which does not really help me to pinpoint the problem. I was not able to find any information with this:

```
D:\APPS\*****\*****>ionic serve -c --verbose
[DEBUG] Reason for not using local CLI: LOCAL_CLI_NOT_FOUND
[DEBUG] CLI flags: { interactive: true, confirm: false }
[DEBUG] { cwd: 'D:\\APPS\\*****\\******', local: false, binPath:
    'C:\\Users\\*****\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\ionic\\bin\\ionic', libPath:
    'C:\\Users\\*****\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\ionic\\dist\\index.js' }
[DEBUG] New daemon pid: 12084
Starting app-scripts server: --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8100 --livereload-port 35729 --dev-logger-port 53703 --consolelogs
--nobrowser - Ctrl+C to cancel
[20:03:59]  watch started ...
[20:03:59]  build dev started ...
[20:03:59]  clean started ...
[20:03:59]  clean finished in 3 ms
[20:03:59]  copy started ...
[20:04:00]  deeplinks started ...
Error: Debug Failure.
at new BuildError (D:\APPS\*****\*****\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\util\errors.js:16:28)
at D:\APPS\*****\*****\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\deep-linking.js:57:21
at <anonymous>
[DEBUG] Error: Debug Failure.
        at new BuildError (D:\APPS\*****\*****\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\util\errors.js:16:28)
        at D:\APPS\*****\*****\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\deep-linking.js:57:21
        at <anonymous>
[20:04:00]  copy finished in 561 ms
```

I tried updating the module app-scripts with `npm install @ionic/app-scripts`, but the same error happens again.  I'm out of ideas... anyone knows how to tackle this one?

Answer (score 0):

I started to go through my project again and noticed that one HTML document and its .ts file were completely altered. Instead of the HTML / .ts code, both files had been replaced with HTML data from github (?!?). I have absolutely no clue how this has happened. When I put my project’s contents back in those files, I was able to run the build successfully. The memory usage never went above 1.5 GB during that.

How this happened is a complete mystery to me. I remember only pushing my code to github before I started to create a test build… I did not download or replace any files directly into my project folder.

Someone might have a better idea about this?

Anyway, I recommend doing the same, just in case you come across a similar error that points to “JavaScript heap out of memory”.